# Can Arduino Mega ADK charge connected smartphone?

Tags: arduino-mega

I suppose Arduino Mega ADK acts as the USB host for the connected smartphone.

Is it capable of providing power to the smartphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mega-adk-rev3), you will see this paragraph:

> NB: Because the MEGA ADK is a USB Host, the phone will attempt to draw power from it when it needs to charge. When the ADK is powered over USB, 500mA total is available for the phone and board.The external power regulator can supply up to 1500mA. 750mA is available for the phone and MEGA ADK board. An additional 750mA is allocated for any actuators and sensors attached to the board. A power supply must be capable of providing 1.5A to use this much current.

So yes (though slowly), if you connect it to a suitable power supply.